# Why is smart contract interact with smart contract necessary？

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm new in blockchain development, I wonder why is it necessary to interact with contract from another contract instead of from a personal EOA address?

Besides the delegatecall, I can't imaging any advantage to use contract to call another deployed contract's functions. As a user, I may rather use ethers or web3js through wallet etc to interact with a deployed smart contract instead.

would you please show me some reasons or necessary cases that I should design my project using a smart contract to interact with another smart contract? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many use cases:

1- Upgradeable contracts or proxy contracts. Since blockchain technology is evolving so fast, it is so hard to write a contract that will be scalable. With proxy contracts, user calls the proxy contract but proxy calls the main contract. if in the future you have to change the logic of the contract, you deploy a new contract and make the proxy contract call this new contract. This way users will not get affected. You can read more about this pattern [here](https://blog.chain.link/upgradable-smart-contracts/)

2- If you ever need to get data from real world, you cannot make an api call because this is not safe and not deterministic. for this reason, we use oracle services which also calls to many other smart contracts behind the scene, gets the results from each, and make a final response to the user. You can read more about [oracles here](https://chain.link/education/blockchain-oracles)

3- another use case is factory contracts. think about it as a class and users keep make an instance of it. that way instead of factory owner pays for the new contract creation, user will be paying for the deployment. you can read more about [factory contracts](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/smart-contract-development/how-to-create-a-smart-contract-factory-in-solidity-using-hardhat)

4- defi platforms have too many smart contracts and they are interacting each other. They keep the logic separate from each other, so they maintain better and see the missing points better. also putting everything in one contract would make contract code is bloated and make a mess. you can read [uniswap](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/concepts/protocol-overview/smart-contracts)

5- another use case to deploy library smart contracts. those are usually mathematical contracts which are deployed once and once u need complex functionalities, instead of you implement in your contract, you use library contracts and use them in your project. You can read about [libraries](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/libraries/)

6- another use case is solving the scalability issues. imagine you have one kitchen and you have to serve all the customers from only one kitchen. As you get more customers, your service will eventually halted. so, there are layer 2 solutions to transfer some of the orders to different kitchens. and this of course happen through smart contract communications. more on [layer 2](https://www.coindesk.com/learn/what-are-layer-2s-and-why-are-they-important/)

7- In general you can use inheritance. You deploy some contracts and inherit the logic from those smart contract. that is why you see openzeppelin contracts always inherit from each other

Comment: Thank you so much. I have an additional question abut factory contract. I understand it as deploying contract on chain for users, so what is it advantages compared with writing an ethers code for users to deploy contract by themselves off chain?

Comment: @Huowuge Sorry but  your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

For example there are some standarts in Ethereum ecosystem. ERC20, ERC721, ERC1155 and others. So when you developing new project, instead of writing it from scratch you could install openzeppelin-contracts, import them and inherit. Afterwards you have this "carcass", on the top of which you can implement some additional functionality/custome code, etc. That approach is way more convenient and secure.

Another great example chainlink-contracts. Via them you can read from oracles. Oracles are smart contracts that keep track of cryptocurrencies prices online. Say you want your users to pay 10$ to participate in lottery/some giveaway. Your contract interacts with chainlink contract and makes sure that amount of eth that user paid is greater or equal to 10$ otherwise it returns error.

In solidity there is no true randomness, but again throughout interacting with chainlink contracts we can reach it. Another chainlink feature is automation contracts, check chainlink documentation to learn more(https://docs.chain.link/). To sum up id say that there is a lot of different protocoles/concepts which easier to interact with than to write it again.
"No need to reinvent the wheel"

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer, which helps a lot.